# How can I call a method from nested fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I have a fragment(this is one tab of my tabhost) `"fragA"` inside other fragment `"fragB"` but I need to call one method of `"fragB"` from `"fragA"`.
when I do from an activity, I do this:

```
FragB detailsFragment=(FragB)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);

detailsFragment.consultaWS(convertIntWebService(categoria),"Pdf");
```

please, help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could finally solve it this way, in `fragA`:

```
FragB parentFragment = (FragB) getChildFragmentManager()
                                      .findFragmentByTag("detallesFragBusqueda");
if (parentFragment != null) {
    parentFragment.consultaWS("", "AllPdf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should facilitate all communication between fragments.  Just create a method in your Activity that a fragment can call, which will tell another fragment to do something.

Answer (score 0):

If FragA is inside FragB, you can do the same from within your FragA.

```
 FragB parentFragment = (FragB)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
 parentFragment.fragmentBMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.
This document explains that how can you communicate between Activity and Fragment 
and also between 2 Fragments

Answer (score 0):

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main_container);
if (fragment != null) {      
       ((TabLayoutFragment)fragment).tabClickDisable();
}
```